# PHP Session Lost after Refreshing the page

Tags: php, session, cookies

I am having this weird issue where when I move away from the page on which I created the session, the session values are lost, this is true for both manual redirecting and redirecting via php header, the code i am using for testing is pretty simple

```
session_start();
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
echo $_SESSION['hi']; // to view the value which was set last time
$_SESSION['hi'] = "yooo";
session_write_close();
```

The Relevant part of my php.ini is as follows

```
Session Support     enabled
Registered save handlers    files user memcache
Registered serializer handlers  php php_binary wddx
**Directive |   Local Value Master | Value**
session.auto_start  Off Off
session.bug_compat_42   Off Off
session.bug_compat_warn Off Off
session.cache_expire    180 180
session.cache_limiter   nocache nocache
session.cookie_domain   no value    no value
session.cookie_httponly Off Off
session.cookie_lifetime 0   0
session.cookie_path /   /
session.cookie_secure   Off Off
session.entropy_file    no value    no value
session.entropy_length  0   0
session.gc_divisor  1000    1000
session.gc_maxlifetime  1440    1440
session.gc_probability  1   1
session.hash_bits_per_character 5   5
session.hash_function   0   0
session.name    PHPSESSID   PHPSESSID
session.referer_check   no value    no value
session.save_handler    files   files
session.save_path   /var/lib/php/session    /var/lib/php/session
session.serialize_handler   php php
session.use_cookies On  On
session.use_only_cookies    On  On
session.use_trans_sid   0   0
```

Comment: do you do session_start () on every page?

Comment: Please show us your codes on the other page too. @Hans is right, please confirm that session_start() appears on both pages.

Comment: @Hans Yes, session_start() is on top of all pages.

Comment: @VincentEdwardGedariaBinua, this is the only page I have, I suspected the problem before writing any other code :)

Comment: What's the reason for using `session_write_close();`? That's not needed.

Comment: Does your session.save_path exist?

Comment: @ksealey, yes, that is not needed, but since nothing was working I tried that as well.

Comment: @Hans, Yes, it exists and have permissions 770.

Comment: 770 won't let the web server write to it unless that directory is owned by the server (or in group). Who is the owner/group?

Comment: Owner is root, group is apache.

Comment: I'm sorry, if this is the only page you have, what exactly do you mean when you "move away from the page..."? The session is lost on this same page or are you hoping to see the session on another? I hope it makes sense.

Comment: you put up error reporting btw, may we know if it throws up any error please?

Comment: It means, first time I load the page, I set a session variable (4th line in my code), than I reload that page again and print that variable (3rd line in my code), but that value is not displayed :)

Comment: Nope, error reporting is not printing anything.